# Array values set in function only work properly for one data type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In this bit of code, I'm trying to get better with pointer arithmetic and arrays. I have a function that creates an array type based on what the user inputs (hence why I went with void * as the function type), and then "hides" the size of the function in the array[-1] spot, so it can always be indexed and have the size right there. Lastly, I cast it as void and return the array.

It works perfectly fine with integers, but no other data types.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * createArray(int size, int soa)
{
int *array;
array = malloc(sizeof(int)+size*soa);
array[0] = size; array++;
return (void*)array;
}

int main(void)
{
int *array;
array = createArray(10, sizeof(int));
double *array2;
array2 = createArray(5, sizeof(double));
printf("%d\n", *(array-1));
printf("%f", *(array2-1));
}
```

My output is :
`10`
`0.000000`

So, it's hiding it correctly for the integer, but something is going wrong for all other data types and I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `double` is probably not the same size as `int` so it isn't going to work. You stored an `int` there and are trying to treat it as `double`. And you only allocated enough space for an `int` too. Even if it was the same size, it's not a `double` value which was stored there. They don't have the same representation.

Comment: ... so you can't pass an `int` value to the `%f` format and expect any sensible outcome.

Comment: Use `size_t` for size, not int. See also `calloc`.

Comment: There are also possible alignment issues.  For example, if `double` needs to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, the allocation code will (normally) return a pointer that is 4-byte aligned, not 8-byte aligned, and the array will be unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Azoros,

Your code works for integers because you define the pointer type as integers.  When you define the pointer type as double, the processor will try to process each element as a double data type.  Internally integers and doubles are stored using different formats.   That is why when you try to retrieve the integer value from a double data type it does not work.

So, if I understand your problem correctly, you want to have an array with its zero element define as an integer that holds the length of the array.  The rest of the elements need to hold data values which could be a different data type then the first element.

I would approach this problem by defining the array pointer as a byte array (void *).  Then when accessing elements, I would just tell the processor what data type it is dealing with.

Here is how this is done in practice:

Change the pointer definition to a byte pointer.

```
void* array;
```

Allocate the array to a size that includes both the array length element along with the data elements.

```
array = calloc(1, INT_SIZ + (noe * soe));
```

Move the size value into the first position of the array.  Note on a Windows x86 machine this will copy 4 bytes of data.

```
memcpy(array, (void*)&noe, INT_SIZ);
```

Return the memory address offset by the size of the first element.  On a x86 machine, this will be offset by 4 bytes

```
return (void*)(((int*)(array)) + 1);
```

Here the full code that utilize the modified createArray routine.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

# define INT_SIZ sizeof(int)
# define GetSize( pt ) ((int *)pt)[-1]
# define GetElement( pt, etype, idx ) ((etype *)pt)[idx]
# define InsertElement( pt, etype, idx, val ) \
  { \
     etype temp = val; \
     memcpy ( (void *) &((etype *)pt)[idx], &temp, sizeof(etype) ); \
  }



void * createArray(int noe,  /* Number of elements */
                   int soe)  /* Size of element */
{
   void *array;

   /* Allocate the array */    
   array = calloc(1, INT_SIZ + (noe * soe));
   if ( array == NULL ) return NULL;

   /* Copy the integer value representing the number of elements to the first
      element in the array */
   memcpy ( array, (void *) &noe, INT_SIZ );


   /* Return the pointer value offset by the size of an int */
   return (void *) (((int *)(array))+1);
}


int main(void)
{
   void *array;
   int i=0;

   array = createArray(10, sizeof(int));
   InsertElement ( array, int, 0, 65534 );

   printf("%d\n",  *(int *)( ((int *)(array)) - 1) );  /* pointer syntax */
   printf("%d\n",  ((int *)array)[-1]  );              /* array syntax   */
   printf("%d\n",  GetSize(array)  );
   printf ( "Element #%d: %d\n", 0, GetElement ( array, int, 0 ) );

   puts ( "\nDemonstrating Array of Doubles --------------------------------");
   array = createArray(10, sizeof(double));
   InsertElement ( array, double, 0, 3.0 );
   InsertElement ( array, double, 1, 3.1 );
   InsertElement ( array, double, 2, 3.2 );

   printf("Array size: %d\n",  GetSize(array)  );
   for ( i=0; i<3; i++ )
      printf ( "Element #%d: %lf\n", i, GetElement ( array, double, i ) );

   free ( ((int *)(array))-1 );
}
```

Here is the output:

```
10
10
10
Element #0: 65534

Demonstrating Array of Doubles --------------------------------
Array size: 10
Element #0: 3.000000
Element #1: 3.100000
Element #2: 3.200000
```

Things to note about the code

1. The array is treated as a zero-base array just like any other C
   array.
2. Although in the routine, I have added a check to see if the memory
   was allocated, a similar check should be done by any callers of the createArray
   routine.
3. The macro definitions were added to make the code more readable.