# C, Why does my custom free function give me the "pointer being freed was not allocated" error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null, free

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array, put some data in it, and then free it and set the array pointer to null so that it can not be accessed in the future. Also, unrelated, but I am storing the size of the array in the first element and then passing it back indexed one up, it is part of the assignment, so hopefully that doesn't confuse anyone.

If I am understanding the error correctly, I am trying to call `free()` on the array that my malloc'ed array was copied in to. This is not allowed because `free()` is not being called on the actual malloc'ed array but rather the one that's holding its values.

If this is the case, how would I fix my call of `free()` to only receive an array address and dereference it like `free(*array);`. Right now I have some mess of asteriscs and a cast and I have no idea why it works. If you know how to fix the free call into the above or just explain why what I have now works, I would greatly appreciate it. My goal is to be able to set the parameter for the custom free function to a void pointer instead of a specific data type pointer. Thanks!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int getSizeArray(void *array);
void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype);
void freeArray(double ** array);


int main(void){

    double * arr = createArray(10, sizeof(double));
    int size = getSizeArray(arr);

    /* using output for error checking
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%f\n", arr[j]);
    }
    */

    void* p = &arr;

    freeArray(p);

}


int getSizeArray(void *array){
    int s = ((int *) array)[-1];
    return s;
}


void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype){
    int * array = malloc((n * sizeOfDatatype) + sizeof(int));
    array[0] = n;
    return (void*) (array + 1);
}


void freeArray(double ** array){
    free(*array);
    *array = NULL;
}
```

EDIT: Look to @JonathanLeffler comment. The issue is with alignment. I switched around some of my code but I had to index back one and not cast in my functions but instead in main

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int getSizeArray(void *array);
void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype);
void freeArray(double ** array);


int main(void){

    double * arr = createArray(10, sizeof(double));
    arr = (void*) (arr + 1);
    int size = getSizeArray(arr);

    /* using output for error checking*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%f\n", arr[j]);
    }

    arr = (double*) (arr - 1);

    freeArray(&arr);

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%f\n", arr[j]);
    }

}


int getSizeArray(void *array){
    int s = ((int *) array)[-1];
    return s;
}


void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype){
    int * array = malloc((n * sizeOfDatatype) + sizeof(int));
    array[0] = n;
    return array;
}


void freeArray(double ** array){
    free(*array);
    *array = NULL;
}
```

Comment: i guess, you pass address of ((int*)array + 1) to the `free()` function instead of the address of  the array itself.  You need to fix it in your freeArray function.

Comment: @Serge could you go into more detail. Right now if I copy and paste what you say, it wouldn't make sense, bc array is not defined in main. how could I access the address of ((int*) array +1) if it is in another function?

Comment: Either you deleted a question from yesterday related to this topic, or one of your colleagues asked about it.  It too was trying to store the length allocated before the pointer returned from the allocation function, and was running into problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler was not me, I am doing this wrong though? Our instructor wants us to store the size of the array and then return the array indexed one past the size, so the size is always available in array[-1].

Comment: The first manifestation of the problem is in this code: `void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype){
    int * array = malloc((n * sizeOfDatatype) + sizeof(int));
    array[0] = n;
    return (void*) (array + 1);
}` — The pointer returned by `malloc()` is appropriately aligned for any type, but there's a distinct probability that the alignment requirement is more strict than the alignment of `int`, so when you return the pointer, it is not properly aligned for some types — such as `double`.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ (Drat; I lost my first draft of this continuation.) The `int` type normally requires 4-byte alignment; on many systems, the `double` type needs 8-byte alignment. That would mean that the returned value is not properly aligned for `double` data.  You probably need to look at C11 [§6.2.8 Alignment of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.8) and you may have to use more space for the array length so that the data is properly aligned (see `max_align_t` in `<stddef.h>`). You should also be using `size_t` for sizes rather than `int`, but that's a mostly trivial fix.

Comment: The question from yesterday was [Array values set in function only work properly for one data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60156221/15168).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provided a [complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164687/11992419) to this problem for another user.  Must be a class assignment.  My version is very similar to yours except I used macros instead of functions.  Anyway, @Serge answer was so close.  It -1 not +1.

Here what I plug into my code and it worked fine:

```
void freeArray(void** array)
{
    free( ((int*)(*array)) - 1 );
    *array = NULL;
}
```

Let me explain what going on.  The C allocation routines are basically doing what you are doing.  They save the array size one word above the actual array.  Follow [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-88/) for more information on how `free()` works.  In our version, we are saving the array size one int (2 words/4 bytes) above the actual array.  Your code was wrong because the address you reference is the 3rd element and not the first.  You need to pass in the address where the array allocation originated which is `((int*)(*array)) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you `free(*array)`, you don't need to `*array = NULL` after that.

Also, you can't cast a `(void *)` onto an `(int *)` and assign it to a `(double *)`.

Lastly, you can't `freeArray(p);` if p is a single pointer since `freeArray(double ** array)` has a parameter of double double-pointer.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean when you say "Also, you can't cast a (void *) onto an (int *) and assign it to a (double *)." I am not getting any error doing this, and if I do not cast it to a double then I can not assign values to the elements, because it will be void.

Comment: @AdamMenker: I share your puzzlement. The comment might be an almost inscrutable way of describing the alignment problems I referred to in my continued [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180618/c-why-does-my-custom-free-function-give-me-the-pointer-being-freed-was-not-all#comment106444118_60180618).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare my modified code.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getSizeArray(void *array);
void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype);
void freeArray(void ** array);


int main(void){

    double * arr = (double *)createArray(10, sizeof(double));
    int size = getSizeArray(arr);

    printf("size of arr %d\n", size);

    // using output for error checking
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%f\n", arr[j]);
    }


    void ** p = (void **)&arr;

    freeArray(p);
    printf("del arr, then arr = %u\n",(unsigned)arr);

}


int getSizeArray(void *array){
    int s = ((int *) array)[-1];
    return s;
}


void * createArray(int n, int sizeOfDatatype){
    int * array = (int*)malloc((n * sizeOfDatatype) + sizeof(int));
    array[0] = n;
    return (void*) (array + 1);
}


void freeArray(void ** array){
    free(((int*)*array)-1);
    *array = NULL;
}
```

output:

```
size of arr 10
0.000000
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
9.000000
del arr, then arr = 0
```

Comment: Could you explain the changes you made, I think yours is very close to what I am trying to do, but it still gets the same error :(

Comment: @AdamMenker I perfected the answer, I think this is what you want

Comment: It's software; it's not perfect, therefore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My english is not good, i mean i added the answer

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe I should use consummate instead of perfected

Comment: I suggest 'improved' is probably a good term.  Many changes are improvements, but few if any lead to perfection.  And I'm mostly joking with you — though there's also a serious message too.  Your English is much better than my Chinese.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  hhhh, Google Translate didn't show this word for me. thank you